# How to change gcc version when compiling with the command line ? (no makefile)

Tags: gcc

I would like to test an older version of gcc for my program, so how can i change the version used for compilation ?
Is there a way to change it directly in the command line ?
(ex: gcc -blabla -o main main.c)

Cheers

Aurel

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a debian-based distro? When I type gcc and hit tab I get other options gcc-4.4 gcc-4.6 gcc-4.8 gcc-4.9 etc - just substitute gcc for gcc-4.6

Comment: Yep, i'm on Ubuntu, when i press tab i have no choices like yours so i guess i have to install the versions first ^^